# SQL Join Need to display Grandfather and Grandson name containg from the family table

Tags: sql, join, inner-join, self-join

A table named 'Family' containing only two column 'Father' and 'Son' and contain below values respectively.

```
Father | Son  
 A     | B  
 B     | C  
 C     | D  
 D     | E
```

---

using join display 'GrandFather' and 'GrandSon' relationship. i.e,

```
GrandFather | GrandSon  
A           | C  
B           | D  
C           | E
```

Comment: We could do this using a CTE . So your result is a table of 2 columns named 'GrandFather' and 'GrandSon' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.Father AS GrandFather, t2.Son AS GrandSon
FROM Family t1 join family t2 ON t1.son = t2.father
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
SELECT a.father as grandfather, b.son as grandson
  FROM family a
  JOIN family b ON (a.son = b.father)
```